# JFoenix: JFXTabPane tab-selected-line color and width

Tags: javafx, jfoenix

I work with the JFoenix-Library and have a problem.

How can I change the width of the tab-selected-line. I tried the following code but it doesnt work:

```
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-selected-line {
-fx-border-color: green;
-fx-stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

I can set the color of the selected line but the width wont work. So i tested it on another way.

I set the border-width and the border-color of the tab like this:

```
.jfx-tab-pane .tab:selected {
-fx-border-width: 0 0 4 0;
-fx-border-color: green;
}
```

But after that, I cant set the selected-line color. It takes the default color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuuEj.png)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-selected-line {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For change stroke color must use `-fx-stroke`
You can use this:

```
.jfx-tab-pane .tab-selected-line {
    -fx-stroke: green;
    -fx-stroke-width: 5pt;
}
```